# JQuery Array made in For Loop, All Elements the Same

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am very new to JQuery, so sorry if this is a naive question.  I am trying to randomize an array of 3 numbers, 35 times.  Each time I shuffle the array of 3-numbers and write to console, it looks like a new shuffle is produced.  However, when I add each new shuffling to an array and print the entirety of its contents, it seems that the array subsists of 35 copies of the last shuffle made.

Thanks in advance!

```
var arr2 = [0,1,2]; 

var seedArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]

var arr2AggregateArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < 35; i++) { 
    seed = seedArray[i];
    shuffle(arr2,seed);
    console.log(arr2);
    arr2AggregateArray[i] =  arr2;
    console.log(arr2); 
}

console.log(arr2AggregateArray);
```

Comment: please share copy of your shuffle function also.

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
arr2AggregateArray[i] =  arr2;
```

puts a *reference* to `arr2` into `arr2AggregateArray`, not a *copy*. All 35 references refer to the same array:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  
| arr2AggregateArray |  
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+              +−−−−−−+
| 0:  *ref*          |−−−+−+−+−+−+−>| arr2 |
| 1:  *ref*          |−−/ / /   /   +−−−−−−+
| 2:  *ref*          |−−−/ /   /    | 0: 2 |
| 3:  *ref*          |−−−−/   /     | 1: 0 |
| ...                |       /      | 2: 1 |
| 34: *ref*          |−−−−−−/       +−−−−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

You need to make a copy. In this case, since it just contains primitives (numbers), a shallow copy will do:

```
arr2AggregateArray[i] =  arr2.slice(0);
```

You haven't shown your `shuffle` function, so I've assumed it shuffles the array in-place. If it returns a *new* shuffled array, then you wouldn't need the `slice` above, but you'd just need to use `shuffle`'s return value.